# Grid AutoSizeColumn performance issue with large table

Tags: wxpython

I have a large grid (~9400 rows x 14 columns), filled using a `wx.grid.GridTableBase`

After the table has been filled I perform an `AutoSizeColum` on all columns:

```
[self.grid.AutoSizeColumn(col) for col in range(self.grid.GetNumberCols())]
```

The issue is that specific operation takes 26 seconds (profiled with cProfile), which is unacceptable for my app'.

Are there alternative ways of doing this autosizing that would take much lower time (< 1 sec) ?

Comment: Have you tried `grid.AutoSizeColumns()` rather than doing them one at a time?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I tried `grid.AutoSizeColumns()` but unfortunately it leads to the same performances. I suppose it is only an overhead of `grid.AutoSizeColumn` with an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on AndersMunch proposal ([see this link on wxpython.org](https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/grid-autosizecolumn-performance-issue-with-large-table/36256))

- sort the data of each column (with pandas for example), and keep only the longest one
- generate the grid with this single-row data and do an `AutoSizeColumns()`
- then replace by real data and regenerate the grid table and inform the grid has changed

Costs less than 0.4 sec for my dataset, compared to the 26 sec initially.